# How to pass data from SelectDateWidget to view and url

Tags: python, django, forms, view, widget

I have a problem how to pass selected data from SelectDateWidget to view and to url.
Now I have the hardcoded data get_success_url in the digest, after the "submit" on the form.

For the SelectDateWidget help, I want to select the month and year for which I want to show selected events.

Here is my form:

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_start = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1980, 2018)))

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('date_start', )
        widgets = {'date_start': SelectDateWidget()}
```

This is my view, where I have hardcoded value for success url:

```
class BookingListView(ListView, FormView):
    model = models.Booking
    form_class = BookingForm
    queryset = models.Booking.objects.all() # order_by('-date_start')
    paginate_by = 80
    template_name = 'events/archive_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'object_list'
    date_field = 'date_start'
    allow_future = True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookingListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['mode'] = 'archive'
        context['form'] = BookingForm()
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('archive:archive_month_numeric', kwargs={'year': 2014, 'month': 10})
```

My url to page where I have events in selected date:

```
url(r'^/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/$', views.ArticleMonthArchiveView.as_view(month_format='%m'), name="archive_month_numeric"),
```